# Are there any disadvantages to leaving a large portion of an SSD unformatted?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I am duel booting Windows and Ubuntu on a solid state hard drive. I have most of my files stored on a secondary hard drive. I was thinking of leaving a large portion of the SSD partitioned and giving both operating systems smaller partitions, so that I can increase their size later as they need to grow (but I don't want to set the size now because I don't know which is going to need more space and it's a real pain to shrink windows partitions. Are their any drawbacks of this system I should be aware of?

Comment: Duel booting? Is that when Windows and Ubuntu fight to see which one boots every time the computer turns on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are no real drawbacks to not fully utilising the disk.  You are not changing the geometry. Partitions may fill earlier, but you should not be concerned about wear levelling as the controller should handle that in the background.

So, only that you will have less overhead space. Are you using a swap partition ? You should put this at the end of the drive, it will be one less to move during a resize. Sometimes it is just easier to pick a number. If you just make it EXT2, you can store backup images of the partitions in files inside ?

Answer (score 1):

"Unformatted" is not the same as over-provisioning, which can improve performance and longevity of the drive in exchange for smaller usable drive size.  Samsung Magician and similar firmware controls give you some control over the SSD over-provisioning.

If you see unformatted space in Windows Disk Management, then it's not helping you.

Comment: Incorrect, this is exactly how Samsung Magician overprovisions. The drive knows the unformatted space is unused, via TRIM.

Comment: @user71659 This may be safe, maybe not. You cannot assume unformatted space is unused, or even that non partitioned space is unused,  Wear levelling should only be concerned with  stats for physical addresses. Overprovisioning should ideally use the gap between the reported geometry and the actual resources for the turnaround....  and trim has nothing to do with wear levelling, it is a zeroing strategy for write performance, even though clusters may be nulled during relocation.